# cURL error 6: Could not resolve host. Mgp25/InstagramAPI

Tags: php, curl, cookies, session-storage, instagramapi-mgp25

I'm using Instagram API by mgp25. 
When my network settings change (connect to different Wifi network) login function throws cURL error 6. 
I guess, It's because of sessions and cookies stored during previous sessions but I'm not so sure. 
I tried to find something on how to reset these sessions or cookies but I was not able to. 
Any help on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you receive has nothing to do with cookies or session except if you are not taking URL where your request goes from the session or cookies. I highly doubt that.

The error you receive is an indication of a network problem and unreachable host.

1. So I advise you check your network, turn off/on VPNs.
2. check if the URL where you are sending your request is correct 100%!

All should be fine if you are sure all network and URLs are correct.

Comment: Yes, the URL is not correct. It works on one wifi network and doesn't not the other. Issue is that the API stores that in a session and doesn't regenerate it when we login from the other WiFi connection.

Comment: When you login from another WiFi you need to generate another login to have your new session. When you kill your WiFI you kill your session. Does this makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with IG spam system, they start blocking you or challenging your users. When you sign up with one IP but later switch to another IP their system will lock your requests for security and send your request challenge_request. Cookies should be fine, as they do not depend on your IP. Create your users on a server that does not change its IP and you can use them for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing proxies.